# PuTTY X11 forwarding: Unsupported authorisation protocol

Tags: putty, xorg, ubuntu-14.04, xauth

I have a Ubuntu 14 running as the "Server" and am trying to use PuTTY on my windows machine as the "Client"

On the Server:
ForwardX11 yes
ForwardX11Trusted yes

On the Client:
PuTTY Configuration: SSH->X11->Enable X11 Forwarding (ticked), with MIT-Magic-Cookie-1
Xming Server running

PuTTY Event Log:

```
2016-09-18 01:02:24 Requesting X11 forwarding
2016-09-18 01:02:24 X11 forwarding enabled
```

**Command:**

```
xclock
```

**Result:**

```
PuTTY X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol
Error: Can't open display: ubuntu3:10.0
```

The above command records this in the PuTTY Event Log:

```
2016-09-18 01:20:22 Received X11 connect request from 127.0.0.1:60167
2016-09-18 01:20:22 Opened X11 forward channel
2016-09-18 01:20:22 Forwarded X11 connection terminated
```

I've tried uninstalling xauth using `apt-get purge xauth` then reinstalling `apt-get install xauth`

Can anyone think of why this is not working? It was working a little while back... am not sure what changed!!?!

**Command:**

```
sudo DISPLAY=localhost:11 XAUTHORITY=/home/<username>/.Xauthority xclock
```

**Result:**

```
PuTTY X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol
Error: Can't open display: localhost:11
```

When I try the same from a another Linux box, I get this error instead of Unsupported authorisation protocol:

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
Error: Can't open display: ubuntu3:10.0
```

I have 2 Ubuntu systems. Named Ubuntu2 and Ubuntu3. Everything seems to work on Ubuntu2. So I started comparing the two...

**xauth list**

`Ubuntu2`

```
ubuntu/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  7c27c83c47f4b323a2855c67e1eeef63
ubuntu/unix:11  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  7c1aa456987ee9face9a35f8aa72acf3
ubuntu2/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  50073df1fac06436a5e724d93730ef64
ubuntu2/unix:11  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  5860938ccf8af0e0f4a00c37ca51feb5
ubuntu2/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  0fa58759ec8e78b735aa3528933464c0
```

`Ubuntu3`

```
localhost:11  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  b6e1bf9dedae8b358133462e3d702547
ip6-localhost:11  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  b6e1bf9dedae8b358133462e3d702547
localhost:13  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  6fe13bad7d70320cf01c1d9ea76ab084
ip6-localhost:13  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  6fe13bad7d70320cf01c1d9ea76ab084
ubuntu3/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  c4bf89ae06d1aca5f36993fe728a5d21
```

**echo $DISPLAY**

`Ubuntu2`

```
localhost:10.0
```

`Ubuntu3`

```
ubuntu3:10.0
```

**which xauth**

`Ubuntu2`

```
/usr/bin/xauth
```

`Ubuntu3`

```
/usr/bin/xauth
```

**Something Strange**

I started comparing different conf files between the two systems. And noticed ip6 was disabled on Ubuntu3 and not on Ubuntu2. So, I tried re-enabling ip6 on Ubuntu3 and no dice. So, I disabled it on Ubuntu2 and it broke X11 forwarding. I don't know why and how ip6 plays a role in this... can someone explain?

Comment: What you need to look at (and post) are the server's logs.

Comment: Checked auth.log and nothing gets added when i run xclock. Is there another log I should be checking?

Comment: All of them. System log, SSHD log, X11 log, dmesg, secure, if you have them, depending on your distro.

Comment: I have 2 ubuntu boxes. Ubuntu2 and Ubuntu3. It works on Ubuntu2 but not on Ubuntu3. When I do `echo $DISPLAY`, I get `localhost:10.0` and `ubuntu3:11.0` respectively. Do you think that has something to do with it? I `export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0` on ubuntu3 and it does not seem to help? Any thoughts?

Comment: After struggling with it for last 3 days! Found the answer here!!! http://serverfault.com/questions/278743/ssh-x11-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Almost there
Oracle Linux 7.x
I had to go into
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Find the lines for X11 and make sure they were active or set

X11Forwarding yes

X11DisplayOffset 10

X11UseLocalhost yes

re-ran putty as oracle and ran the runInstaller... and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error using PuTTY (from Windows 10) whenever accessing Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. (Xming Server is running in Windows)

```
    PuTTY X11 proxy: Authorisation not recognised
    Error: Can't open display: sdnhubvm:10.0
```

I solved my problem by modifying the file `sshd_config` inside `/etc/ssh/`.

Steps I took:

1. Open file `sshd_config` using an editor such as vim.

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
   ```
2. Locate the line that says `X11UseLocalHost no` (was around lines #65-67)

   ```
   65 X11DisplayOffset 10
   66 X11UseLocalHost no
   67 PrintMotd no
   ```
3. Comment out line `#X11UseLocalHost no` and save.

   ```
   65 X11DisplayOffset 10
   66 # X11UseLocalHost no
   67 PrintMotd no
   ```
4. Reboot
5. Start PuTTY

   ```
   putty.exe -X 192.168.245.4
   ```
6. Test it

   ```
   ubuntu@sdnhubvm:~$ xclock
   ```
7. It now works. Done.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem except that when starting putty connection there was an error message on the server saying :
/usr/bin/xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /home/retud/.Xauthority"

This was because the user didn't have the good right on the server (1003 instead of retud in this case).
2 drwxr-xr-x 7 1003 retud    14 Nov 25  2020 .
My solution to solve the problem was to change the owner of the directory
retud@LP0X:~$ sudo su -
root@LP0X:/home#
root@LP0X:/home# chown -R retud  /retud

It solves the problem.
My two cents.